# How can we return an empty collection using yield?

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable, yield-return

I have following extension function:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Select<T>(this IDataReader reader,
                               Func<IDataReader, T> selector)
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        yield return selector(reader);
    }
}
```

which is being used like:

```
var readFields = dsReader.Select(r =>
{
    var serviceResponse = myService.Decrypt<DateTime>(r.GetString(DATE_VALUE), r.GetInt32(DEK_ID));

    if (serviceResponse.IsSuccessful)
    {
        return new DataField<DateFieldValue>
        {
            FieldValue = new DateFieldValue { Data = serviceResponse.Value }
        };
    }
    return null;
});

if (!readFields.IsCollectionNullOrEmpty())
                        returnFinalFields.AddRange(readFields);
```

The problem I am facing here is that even if serviceResponse.IsSuccessful is false the readFields is not empty it contains an enumerable with an item that is null. Is there a way we can return an empty collection here?

Comment: `Enumerable.Empty<T>();`

Comment: Is there a way to check before the reader.Read() to see if there is data, and return null there before going into the while?

Comment: @Neil returning null from an expected `IEnumerable<T>` is almost always an anti pattern.

Comment: OK, then just return an empty list.  Either way, not going into the loop is the key here.

Comment: ( @DavidL if you could point me in the direction of some useful articles saying why this is an anti-pattern, then I could bash some developers over the heads with it)

Comment: you could add a `Where(x => x != null)` ?

Comment: @MarcGravell thats what I generally do.

Comment: @Neil http://blogs.encodo.ch/news/view_article.php?id=388 or any other various threads including SO questions.  The point is that by potentially returning null, you are forced to do additional checks...first for null and THEN for the presence of the item.  Returning empty collections instead of null allows you to always access the collection directly without ever needing to worry about NullReferenceExceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting (mis?) use of `Select`. Your issue is you return a null from the `Select` delegate when `IsSuccessful` is `false`. Since not returning a value from `Select`'s delegate isn't an option, filter afterwards:

```
var readFields = dsReader.Select(r => {
    var serviceResponse = myService.Decrypt<DateTime>(r.GetString(DATE_VALUE), r.GetInt32(DEK_ID));

    if (serviceResponse.IsSuccessful)
        return new DataField<DateFieldValue> {
            FieldValue = new DateFieldValue { Data = serviceResponse.Value }
        };
    else
        return null;
}).Where(df => df != null);
```

Answer (score 2):

The real problem here is that you don't want to be selecting out a `null` value when the service doesn't have a successful response.  You'll want to filter out the successful responses as a part of your query:

```
var readFields = from r in dsReader
    let serviceResponse = myService.Decrypt<DateTime>(r.GetString(DATE_VALUE), r.GetInt32(DEK_ID))
    where serviceResponse.IsSuccessful
    select new DataField<DateFieldValue>
    {
        FieldValue = new DateFieldValue { Data = serviceResponse.Value }
    };
```

Comment: Or in lambda syntax `var readFields = dsReader.Select(r => myService.Decrypt<DateTime>(r.GetString(DATE_VALUE), r.GetInt32(DEK_ID))).Where(sr => sr.IsSuccessful).Select(new DataField<DateFieldValue> { FieldValue = new DateFieldValue { Data = serviceResponse.Value } });`

Comment: BTW, very nice inversion of the problem to make it more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

The `Select` method could check the returned result and only yield it's value when valid. For example not `null`:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Select<T>(this IDataReader reader, Func<IDataReader, T> selector)
    where T:class
{   
    while (reader.Read())
    {   
        var res = selector(reader);
        if(res!=null)
            yield return res;
    }
}
```

Although as stated by Servy, that would normally not belong in a regular `Select`. The method could be called something like `SelectValidValues` to avoid confusion.

Another way would be to have the lambda parameter return a Tuple containing both the result and if it's valid.
Yet another way is to have an optional parameter (as a value or an extra predicate function) that checks which values are valid

Comment: Then it's not selecting any more.  This doesn't belong in a `Select` method.

Comment: @Servy indeed, but maybe OP have different idea how `Select` should behave? Renaming to something `SelectNotEmpty` would be fine for public code.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov That's just creating a new problem.  There's a reason LINQ doesn't have a `SelectNotEmpty` method.  If you want to project, you use a projection method, if you want to filter, you use a filter method.  You don't combine them into a single method that does two unrelated things.  Additionally, it's still semantically wrong here to be using `null` values at all as a representation of failed responses; *that* is the problem to fix.

Comment: @Servy should not you vote/comment/edit question in addition than? (Obviously if question would be about filtering just regular `.Where(x => x!=null)` would be much better - but question about returning empty collection  at least based on title).

Comment: @Servy The solution is based upon the idea that the OP is creating a generic extension method (not specifically Linq related). Although I would agree that returning null is not the best way, imho an extension method can combine functionality. Personally I'd use the extra lambda function. One could say that Linq sometimes combines lesser functionality that way such as `Count(predicate)` (ok, may not be the best comparison :D )